# How to add rows for missing categories

Tags: sql

I have a table that includes a row for each course a student has taken. I need a query that will return a row for math and English (with a credit of 0) even if the student didn't take one of those courses during that term.

I have tables GRADES:

| Student | Year | Term | CourseTitle | Subject | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | Trimester 1 | Writing 1 | English | .5 |
| 1 | 2022 | Trimester 1 | Algebra 1 | Math | .5 |
| 1 | 2022 | Semester 2 | Writing 2 | English | .5 |
| 1 | 2022 | Semester 2 | PE 1 | PE | .5 |
| 1 | 2023 | Semester 1 | Reading 1 | English | .5 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 1 | Algebra 1 | Math | .5 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 2 | Algebra 2 | Math | .5 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 4 | Biology | Science | .5 |

I want:

| Student | Year | Term | CourseTitle | Subject | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | Trimester 1 | Writing 1 | English | .5 |
| 1 | 2022 | Trimester 1 | Algebra 1 | Math | .5 |
| 1 | 2022 | Semester 2 | Writing 2 | English | .5 |
| 1 | 2022 | Semester 2 | NULL | Math | 0 |
| 1 | 2022 | Semester 2 | PE 1 | PE | .5 |
| 1 | 2023 | Semester 1 | Reading 1 | English | .5 |
| 1 | 2023 | Semester 1 | NULL | Math | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 1 | NULL | English | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 1 | Algebra 1 | Math | .5 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 2 | NULL | English | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 2 | Algebra 2 | Math | .5 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 4 | NULL | English | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 4 | NULL | Math | 0 |
| 2 | 2020 | Quarter 4 | Biology | Science | .5 |

How can I accomplish this?

I've tried:

```
WITH MathEnglish AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Subject
    FROM Grades
    WHERE Subject IN ('English', 'Math')
), Terms AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Term
    FROM Grades
),  Combined AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MathEnglish
    CROSS JOIN Terms
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Student, Year, 
    c.Term, g.CourseTitle,
    COALESCE(g.Subject, c.Subject), g.Credit
FROM 
    Combined c
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Grades g ON c.Term = g.Term
```

...but that doesn't do it. I need a different approach, but I'm not sure what it is.

Note: If a student didn't earn any credits in a term, I don't need Math and English rows

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/000c2b/7

Comment: When editing, highlight the data and click `{}`.

Comment: It appears you only want the math/english row in the result set, and you don't actually want the math/english with 0 credits INSERTed into the database, so I edited your question to say "I need a query that will return a row for math and English".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was close, but we want to also include students *before* combining instead of via `FULL JOIN`. The `FULL JOIN` would still have a placeholder row for each student combination, but the ID value would be NULL, so combining in advance is necessary.

We also want to be more precise on the final join, and once we do that we no longer need the final `DISTINCT`:

```
WITH Subjects AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Subject
    FROM Grades
    WHERE Subject IN ('English', 'Math')
)
, Terms AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Year, Term
    FROM Grades
)
, Students AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Student
    FROM Grades
)
,  Combined AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Subjects
    CROSS JOIN Terms
    CROSS JOIN Students
)
SELECT c.Student, c.Year, c.Term, c.Subject, g.CourseTitle, g.Credit
FROM  Combined c
LEFT JOIN Grades g ON c.Term = g.Term AND c.Subject = g.Subject AND c.Student = g.Student
```

Any SIS (Student Information System) worth using will also give you a way to get terms, courses, and students without needing to look through every enrollment record.

Finally, I suspect you don't need every possible combination of Student/Term, but only combinations in which a student actually participates (even if in subjects other than Math and English). In this way, students who graduate, move away, or otherwise leave the school won't pollute the results for terms after they are gone or before they arrive.

If so, it looks like this:

```
WITH Subjects AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Subject
    FROM Grades
    WHERE Subject IN ('English', 'Math')
)
, StudentTerms AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Student, Year, Term
    FROM Grades
)
,  Combined AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Subjects
    CROSS JOIN StudentTerms
)
SELECT c.Student, c.Year, c.Term, c.Subject, g.CourseTitle, g.Credit
FROM  Combined c
LEFT JOIN Grades g ON c.Term = g.Term AND c.Subject = g.Subject AND c.Student = g.Student
```

Comment: If you compare the queries at https://dbfiddle.uk/tv53KHLD, can you explain the different results? (Only change I made was the leading Subjects cte.)

Comment: @jarlh Yes. The first one, with the table-value constructor, only creates a table with one row and two columns, so there was no `Math` subject. It should look like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/VjvS_jb6

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid now... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jarlh I work at a college, with a bunch of PhDs, and I can confidently say even the smartest people make dumb mistakes from the time to time ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, this was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no keys for the data you provided, the joins are going to be a little bit more complex when self-joining the table.
This is what I came up with:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT g.Student
    ,g.[Year]
    ,g.Term
    ,Subs.[Subject]
FROM #Grades g
    CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT g.[Subject]
                FROM #Grades g
                WHERE g.[Subject] IN ('English','Math')
                ) Subs
)
SELECT CTE.[Student]
    ,CTE.[Year]
    ,CTE.Term
    ,g.CourseTitle
    ,CTE.[Subject]
    ,ISNULL(g.Credit,0) [Credit]
FROM CTE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Grades g
        ON CTE.Student = g.Student
        AND CTE.[Year] = g.[Year]
        AND CTE.Term = g.Term
        AND CTE.[Subject] = g.[Subject]
UNION
SELECT *
FROM #Grades g
WHERE g.[Subject] NOT IN ('English','Math')
```

Here I used Temporary Tables in tandem with a CTE.

Output:

[image]

You can probably figure out some adjustments to make it simpler. I decided to separate the English-Math subjects into their own object because they needed to be evaluated differently. Then I appended the rest of the data with the UNION clause.